# PySpark - Using rdd reduce function throws a Py4JJavaError

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I've been trying to run this code, and when it reaches `dist_reduced = dist_mapped.reduce(reducer)` it throws a Py4JJavaError. I've tried this on 3 different machines, and I get the same error.

`Java version "1.8.0_202", Python 3.12.1, PySpark 3.5.0`

##### Code

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
from util import *
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

cols = ['sentiment', 'id', 'date', 'query_string', 'user', 'text']
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', encoding='latin1', names=cols)

data = df['text'].tolist()

conf = SparkConf().setAppName('MapReduce').setMaster('local[4]')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

dist = sc.parallelize(data)

def mapper(text):
    words = text.split()
    cleaned = map(clean_word, words)
    filtered = filter(word_not_in_stopwords, cleaned)
    return Counter(filtered)
    
def reducer(cnt1, cnt2):
    cnt1.update(cnt2)
    return cnt1

dist_mapped = dist.map(mapper)
dist_reduced = dist_mapped.reduce(reducer)

dist_data_reduced.most_common(5)
```

##### Traceback

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[10], line 2
      1 dist_mapped = dist.map(mapper)
----> 2 dist_reduced = dist_mapped.reduce(reducer)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py:1924, in RDD.reduce(self, f)
   1921         return
   1922     yield reduce(f, iterator, initial)
-> 1924 vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
   1925 if vals:
   1926     return reduce(f, vals)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py:1833, in RDD.collect(self)
   1831 with SCCallSiteSync(self.context):
   1832     assert self.ctx._jvm is not None
-> 1833     sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
   1834 return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, self._jrdd_deserializer))

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py:1322, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1316 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1317     self.command_header +\
   1318     args_command +\
   1319     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1321 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1322 return_value = get_return_value(
   1323     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1325 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1326     if hasattr(temp_arg, "_detach"):

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2) (Corsair executor driver): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    ...
```

##### System Viarables

- `HADOOP_HOME = C:\hadoop`
- `SPARK_HOME = %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pyspark`
- `Path = %HADOOP_HOME%\bin`
- `Path = %SPARK_HOME%\bin`

##### User Viarables

- `JDK_HOME = %JAVA_HOME%`
- `JRE_HOME = %JAVA_HOME%\jre`
- `Path = %JAVA_HOME%\lib`
- `Path = %JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib`

Comment: Is your python executable in PATH?

Comment: @RinatVeliakhmedov Would that be in the user or system variables?

Answer (score 0):

from the trace log its clear that it not able to find python3

Check if Python 3 is installed on the system running the Corsair executor driver. Use `python3 --version` or `which python3` to confirm.

or

Ensure the directory containing the python3 executable is included in the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: `python3 --version` is an invalid command, didn't work.

Comment: mostly this means you don't have python3 setup in your executors